# How to fetch data effectively from kestrel queue

Tags: java, message-queue, kestrel

For some reason we plan to use kestrel queue in our project. We do some demons, the main problem is how to to fetch data from queue with low CPU utilization and effectively. The way we implemented to fetch  is  if we failed to fetch data from queue more than 5 times, we sleep the thread 100ms to reduce the CPU utilization.

```
while (running) {
            try {
                LoginLogQueueEntry data = kestrelQueue.fetch();
                if (null != data && data.isLegal()) {
                    entryCacheList.add(data); //add the data to the local caceh
                    resetStatus();
                } else {
                    failedCount++;
                    //if there is no data in the kestrel and the local cache is not empty, insert the data into mysql database
                    if (failedCount == 1 && !entryCacheList.isEmpty()) {
                        resetStatus();
                        insertLogList(entryCacheList); // insert current data into database
                        entryCacheList.clear(); //empty local cache
                    }

                    if (failedCount >= 5 && entryCacheList.isEmpty()) {
                    //fail 5 times. Sleep current thread. 
                        failedCount = 0;
                        Thread.sleep((sleepTime + MIN_SLEEP_TIME) % MAX_SLEEP_TIME);
                    }
                }
                //Insert 1000 rows once
                if (entryCacheList.size() >= 1000) {
                    insertLogList(entryCacheList);
                    entryCacheList.clear();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warn(e.getMessage());
            }
```

Is there any other good way to do so? The perfect the way i think is the queue can notice to the worker that we got data and fetch them .

Answer (score 3):

See the "Blocking Fetches" section at http://robey.lag.net/2008/11/27/scarling-to-kestrel.html

Answer (score 2):

Blocking reads are described here, under "Memcache commands": https://github.com/robey/kestrel/blob/master/docs/guide.md

You can add option flags to a get command by separating them with slashes, so to fetch an item from the "jobs" queue, waiting up to one second:

```
get jobs/t=1000
```

If nothing shows up on the queue in one second, you'll get the same empty response, just one second later than you're getting it now. :)

It's important to tune your response timeout when you do this. If you use a blocking read with a timeout of one second, but your client library's response timeout is 500 milliseconds, the library will disconnect from the server before the blocking read is finished. So make sure the response timeout is greater than the timeout you're using in the read request.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a blocking get.  I couldn't track down the API docs, but I found an article suggesting that it's possible in kestrel.